# How to determine algebraically if the vertex of a quadratic equation is inside a 2D triangle?

Tags: systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry, quadratics

The quadratic equation is $y=x^2-2x+C$.

The triangle`s coordinates are for example, $(0,0)$ $(3,0)$ $(3,4)$.
How do a I find the interval for the values of C for which the vertex of the quadratic equation is inside or outside the triangle?

The method proposed by @prakash chandel works if only one point is to be calculated.

Comment: Forget the quadratic equation for a moment. If you were given a random point $(x,y)$, how might you decide whether or not it’s inside the triangle?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
compute the area of $\Delta$ ABC.let new point is X has cordinate ($x_{1}$,$x_{2}$). compute the area of $\Delta$XBC,$\Delta$XAC,and $\Delta$XBA  .if $\Delta$ABC=$\Delta$XBC+$\Delta$XBA+$\Delta$XAC then points lie inside or on the the triangle otherwise outside.

Comment: This method is indeed effective to find out if point X in particular is in the triangle but how do I find all possible values of C?

Comment: find the intersection points of the triangle and parabola,and make some visualization (draw the figure of intersecting parabola with triangle on xy plane)